# Update elements inside a array MongoDB using Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

**A sample JSON Document**

```
{
"_id" : "ab85cebc-8c7a-43bf-8efc-1151ccaa4f84",
"address" : {
    "city" : "Bangalore",
    "postcode" : "560080",
    "countrycode":"in",
    "street" : "SADASHIVNAGAR,SANKEY TANK RD"
},
"brand" : "Shell",
"prices" : [ 
    {
        "fuelType" : "DIESEL",
        "price" : 52.7
    }, 
    {
        "fuelType" : "PETROL",
        "price" : 67.05
    }
]
}
```

- I have around `20 docs` for `brand:Shell` with different location in and around Bangalore.
- For all those I have to update `Diesel` and `Petrol` price.

Say current `DIESEL` and `PETROL` prices are `57.9` and `71.4` respectively?

How do I update all document with these latest price using `JAVA (using Eclipse IDE)`

**Code (in complete)**

```
public class UpdateGasstationFuelPrice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase( "notes" );

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = db.getCollection( "gasstation" ).find( new BasicDBObject( "address.countrycode","in" )
        .append("address.city","Bangalore")
        .append("brand","Shell")).iterator();

    if (cursor.hasNext()){
        Document doc = cursor.next();
    }
    client.close();
}
}
```

**Update with Query**

```
  db.getCollection("gasstation").update({"address.countrycode":"in","address.city":"Bangalore","brand":"Shell"},   
            //Query to get the position
            { 
              "prices":  { $exists: true }  
            },
            // Use the positional $ operator to update specific element (which matches your query    
            { 
              $set: 
                  { 
                    //set value specific to elements field/key
                    "prices" : [
                        {
                            "fuelType" : "DIESEL",
                            "price" : 502.7
                        }, 
                        {
                            "fuelType" : "PETROL",
                            "price" : 607.05
                        }
                      ] 
                  } 
            } 
        );
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far to update? Have you read docs of updating array fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a specific key/value inside of an array field with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064450/updating-a-specific-key-value-inside-of-an-array-field-with-mongodb)

Comment: @titi23 This query i have written to fetch the doc from MongDB     ```MongoCursor<Document> cursor = db.getCollection( "gasstation" ).find( new BasicDBObject("address.city","Bangalore")
   .append("brand","Shell")).iterator();```

Comment: Please add it in the question and try serching in SO. You can find some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot updated util you know the position of the element which you want to update.

So basically what you can do is:

1. You need to query to seek the position.
2. Use the positional operator and update the array.

> ```
> db.gasstation.update(    
>     //Query to get the position
>     { 
>       "prices.fuelType":  "DIESEL"  
>     },
>     // Use the positional $ operator to update specific element (which matches your query    
>     { 
>       $set: 
>           { 
>             "prices.$" : 
>               //Element/new value to update
>                {
>                  "fuelType" : "DIESEL",
>                  "price" : 999.7
>                } 
>           } 
>     } 
> );
> ```

If you want just to update only specific field inside the json element embedded in the array you can do as follows:

> ```
> db.gasstation.update(    
>     //Query to get the position
>     { 
>       "prices.fuelType":  "DIESEL"  
>     },
>     // Use the positional $ operator to update specific element (which matches your query    
>     { 
>       $set: 
>           { 
>             //set value specific to elements field/key
>             //i.e. Update documents in an Array
>             "prices.$.price" : 999.7 
>           } 
>     } 
> );
> ```

---

**Updates based on comments:**

> ```
> db.gasstation.update(    
>     //Query to match
>     {
>       "address.city":"Bangalore",
>       "brand":"Shell",
>       "countrycode":"in",
>       "prices": { $exists: true }
>     },
>     // Use $set operator & overwrite entire array
>     { 
>       $set: 
>           { 
>             //Overwrite value
>             "prices" : [
>                 {
>                     "fuelType" : "DIESEL",
>                     "price" : 502.7
>                 }, 
>                 {
>                     "fuelType" : "PETROL",
>                     "price" : 607.05
>                 }
>               ] 
>           } 
>     } 
> );
> ```

Comment: How do i do it for ```Petrol``` and ```Diesel``` together and also for 20 documents in a single command? is it possible?

Comment: @ShreyasRaoB You can frame your query such that it gets all the 20 or more elements and update the same way. Its actually easier further to tweak based on the above mentioned code in your way

Comment: @ShreyasRaoB: Actually if you are updating both together, why you need to find/ seek positions, you can blindly set both of them like a overwrite. Doesn't it that work for you?

Comment: I am new, Bit confused on how to write query too. I need to use find/ seek position beacuse fuelprice are different for both fuletype. So if one doc contain both ```DIESEL and PETROL``` the i have to update prices specificalyy to each one.

Comment: prices are different. My intention is to update these prices in all matching doc

Comment: @ShreyasRaoB: Check the latest update query FYR, you can update both based on some query isn't it ? I am update collection's all docs where prices field exists.

Comment: Check **Update with Query** .Is this a correct update query (interms of format)

Comment: @ShreyasRaoB No its not, I will update it in my answer.. Check it

Comment: @ShreyasRaoB WHERE IS `address.countrycode` in your sample document ? Simply putting a condition ? How will it work dude?

Comment: I missed that line in JSON doc that i have posted i guess while editing.

Comment: Now it worked!!!! Thanks for letting me know how to solve the problem...